# VS Code Ionic 3 - Intellisense works inside constructor but not anywhere else

Tags: visual-studio-code, ionic3

VS Code Ionic 3 - Intellisense works inside constructor but not anywhere else.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The `this` object is different inside `function`.. Try in arrow function

Comment: suraj is right, try with `test = () => { /* should work here now */ }`

Comment: @suraj Thanks that works. May I ask what is the ES5 equivalent and how why doesn't this code work?

Comment: @sebaferreras Yes I tried, thanks, but what will be the ES5 equivalent to this and could you guide me to why current syntax doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use arrow function instead of `function` as `this` object will be different.

```
test = () => { 
   this.navCtrl.push(CaseDetailsPage);
 }
```

Since you are using Ionic 3, the class function will be:

```
test(){
       this.navCtrl.push(CaseDetailsPage);
}
```

Since `this` was different the VSCode Intellisense did not detect `navCtrl` type .

Comment: Thanks suraj. I didn't notice that this was a  function expression and not declaration.